# error al parsear JSON - Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Tags: json

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
 Error: Parse error on line 12:<br>
...0:00:00",    "title": "      LISTA DE TRABAJO<br> 
--------------------^<br>
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Al momento de generar el siguiente JSON:

```
[{
    "id": "905989",
    "resourceId": "203",
    "start": "2016-01-04T00:00:00",
    "end": "2016-01-04T00:00:00",
    "title": "Se agregó a la carta de término las observaciones referentes a la eliminación del candado del identificador MS, investigación de fundamento legal sobre multas y sanciones a considerar. "
}, {
    "id": "905990",
    "resourceId": "27",
    "start": "2016-01-04T00:00:00",
    "end": "2016-01-04T00:00:00",
    "title": "      LISTA DE TRABAJO DIARIO                                     HORA    CONCEPTO    DLLS    M.N EMPRESA #FACTURA    EMPRESA                                     abrir puertas diariamente                       limpieza de oficinas diariamente        test                        3 a 5               sanmarcos       10 a 12             saucillos       2 a 4   cheq            human resaurce      test10 a 12 cheq            baja tecnica        test12 a 1              compra de pastel        test10 a 12 cheq            dela    inventory   invemtory2 a 4              mueblex de b.c      test10 a 11 usb         draci sport     test11 a 12 recoger     usb         draci sport     test12 a 1  fact            femsa       test2 a 4   cheq            cresus      invemtory                                                                       "
}, {
    "id": "905991",
    "resourceId": "203",
    "start": "2016-01-04T00:00:00",
    "end": "2016-01-04T00:00:00",
    "title": "Junta con Evelyn, Carlos, Lorena y Vicente para determinar el procedimiento para actualizar las modificaciones de tarifa, anexo 22. Se acordó agendar una reunión con Benjamin, Jesús y Daniel para ver aspectos técnicos. Revisión, análisis de Anexo 22. "
}]
```

¿A qué se debe el error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**EDIT:** Al momento de colocar el JSON aquí (stackoverflow) y verficarlo usando JSONlint me aparece sin error.

Comment: Yo no tengo ningún error al parsear : https://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/9wrannfw/

Comment: @Carlos, el json luce bien, creo que es importante que indiques con qué herramienta/biblioteca estás obteniendo este error, y si hay código de por medio, que pongas el código relevante.

Comment: Al momento de colocar el JSON aquí me aparece sin error

Comment: @CarlosOro, revisa que caracteres tienes incorrectos, pueden ser “ o caracteres no imprimibles.

Comment: ¿SQL me genera el JSON de title con un TAB en vez de espaciado simple, eso es lo que impide que se genere correctamente?

Comment: Si! un caracter no imprimible, si la comillas son correctas entonces el problema es ese tab que se ve como un espacio.

Comment: Si, las comillas están correctas, modifiqué mi query para que reemplazara el TAB por un espacio. Gracias

Comment: @CarlosOro ya no debes tener problemas!, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pudiera causar tu error:

> JSON - Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{',
>   '[', got 'undefined'

es que estes usando en tu .json el carácter `“` en lugar de comillas dobles que sería `"`, También pudieran ser caracteres no imprimibles en los espacios.

En el .json que agregas en tu pregunta no hay ningún problema.

Revisa el valor de "title"  en el segundo elemento, podrías tener algo como esto:

```
 "title": “      LISTA DE TRABAJO DIARIO                                     HORA    CONCEPTO    DLLS    M.N EMPRESA #FACTURA    EMPRESA                                     abrir puertas diariamente                       limpieza de oficinas diariamente        test                        3 a 5               sanmarcos       10 a 12             saucillos       2 a 4   cheq            human resaurce      test10 a 12 cheq            baja tecnica        test12 a 1              compra de pastel        test10 a 12 cheq            dela    inventory   invemtory2 a 4              mueblex de b.c      test10 a 11 usb         draci sport     test11 a 12 recoger     usb         draci sport     test12 a 1  fact            femsa       test2 a 4   cheq            cresus      invemtory                                                                       ”,
```